# Manifold without point homotopy equivalent to wedge of $2$-spheres.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Let $F$ be a closed, simply connected four-manifold. Let $F'$ be obtained from $F$ by removing a point. How do I see that $F'$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of $S^2$'s?

Comment: Have you tried computing the homology of $F'$?

Comment: See Hatcher 4C.

Comment: @MikeMiller Proposition 4C.3?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is: *if and only if $\pi_1(F)=1$*.

By cellular approximation theorem we have $\pi_1(F)=\pi_1(F')$, so if $F'$ is a bouquet of spheres, our assumption is satisfied.

In the opposite direction, by $\pi_1(F)=1$ we have $H_1(F)=H^3(F)=0$ using Poincare duality. Therefore, by universal coefficient theorem, $H_2(F)$ has no torsion and $H^1(F)=0$. So, using Poincare duality again, we have $H_3(F)=0$.

By extision, $F$ and $F'$ have the same homology except $H_4$, so $\pi_2(F')=\mathbb Z^k$ for some $k$, and we may to construct a map $\vee_k S^2 \to F'$ that will be an isomorphism on $\pi_2$. Such a map will be also an equivalence on homology, so we have a desired statement.

Comment: Your answer is quite terse. Is it possible you could add a bit more detail/clarification for someone who's a bit slow like me?

Comment: @user378405 i added some details, does it become more understandable?

Comment: If the manifold is not orientable, then I don't see how Poincaré duality can be used?

Comment: @arkeet in this case it actually is, by $\pi_1=1$

Comment: Ah, simply connected implies orientable. OK.